# Java unusual behaviour of random numbers

Tags: java

I came across a code snippet on internet. Here it goes

```
  public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random random = new Random(441287210);  

    for(int j=0;j<10;j++) { 

           System.out.print(random.nextInt(10)+" ");  

    } 
}

}
```

Everytime i run it it prints `1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1` . There might be a strong reason for it.

Why is this behaviour observed.

Here is the source --> http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/10/weird-funny-java.html

Comment: Why does it surprise you that there is a particular seed that would generate this exact sequence of random integers?

Comment: The "every time" part is because it's using the same seed. That particular seed probably has the 1 in 10,000,000,000 chance that it returns 1 for the first ten times.

Comment: This is a bit like successfully guessing last week's lottery numbers.

Comment: Sorry, [couldn't resist](http://search.dilbert.com/comic/Random%20Number%20Generator).

Comment: I guess this is a another good reason for bringing in the lava lamp: http://hackaday.com/2005/06/05/lava-lamp-random-number-generator/

Comment: @BoristheSpider [couldn't resist either](http://xkcd.com/221/)

Answer (score 8):

You're initializing the *pseudorandom* number generator to a specific state, which means that it will always produce the same output across runs. It looks like someone just found a seed that happens to produce an interesting series of results.

Answer (score 1):

Every `Random` seed generates identical sequences of numbers. 441287210 seed generates this sequence, just as any other generated sequence...

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html):

> If two instances of Random are created with the same seed, and the
>   same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and
>   return identical sequences of numbers

Comment: I thought I've used quotes... Thanx!